# How to make instrumented test if I need to use @Composable?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-jetpack-compose, instrumented-test

I had an instrumented test that worked, however, then was added additional param to the object which required to call the `@Composable` function, so the entire test method should be marked as `@Composable`, so I added this annotation to the function, however, it starts to throw the error:

```
org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'entpay.awl.ui.component.showpage.ScreenKtTest':
1. Method testDetails should have no parameters
```

So, the method looks like this

```
    @Test
    @Composable.   <------ Composable annotation
    fun testDetails() {
       ....

        val window: WindowSize = rememberWindowSize()   <------ This method is Composable
      
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            Details(
                config = ...,
                windowSize = window
            )
        }
   }
```

I am a new in instrumental testing, however, I assume that I can't use `@Composable` methods in testing directly

How to make it work?

**UPD**

I also tried to put the `window` line in `setContent`, result the same

```
....
composeTestRule.setContent {
            val window: WindowSize = rememberWindowSize()

            Details(
                config = ...,
                windowSize = window
            )
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your `window` line in the `setContent()` lambda, before your `Details()` call?

Comment: @CommonsWare updated in the question

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry, looks like it works, I just forgot to delete the import which is redundant after that line was moved, thanks!